# Help! Error: The local variable transactionType may not have been initialized

Tags: java

I get this 
Error: The local variable transactionType may not have been initialized

but the thing is it is initialized in my if statement!

```
if (transactionChar == 'w')
  transactionType = "Withdrawal"; 

else if (transactionChar == 'd')
  transactionType = "Deposit" ;
```

then when i go to print out transactionType, it wont let me because it gives me that error!
 my declaration statement looks something like this.

```
String transactionType;
char transactionChar;
```

Please Help. I have been trying to figure it out for the past 4 hours!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your variables:

```
String transactionType = "";
char transactionChar = '';
```

(not sure on the char as I use C# usually).

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize transaction type in every possible condition. That includes an else statement. For example:

```
if (transactionChar == 'w') 
  transactionType = "Withdrawal";
else if (transactionChar == 'd')
  transactionType = "Deposit";
else
  transactionType = "Something else";
```

Comment: That's not initializing the variable, that's simply assignment. This isn't a solution at all because it doesn't guarantee that `transactionChar` has ever been initialized/assigned-to before the check `transactionChar == 'w'` is made.

Comment: That was not his question. The error was: "transaction**Type** may not have been initialized". My code initializes transactionType in every case.

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler analyzed the flow of your code and saw that if transactionChar is neither 'w' or 'd', then transactionType would be left uninitialized.  Either initialize the variable or provide an else clause that sets a value regardless of program flow.

Comment: Thanks alot! I set String transactionType = ""; and it fixed the problem.